# Communication between two subdomains. Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, subdomain

I'm adding a bulletin board to my Zend-driven site, and am using an open source one called Phorum.  While it would be theoretically possible to integrate Phorum into my Zend site, it's already self contained, and not designed to run through a controller.

My solution was to make a sub-domain for Phorum, which worked quite well.  However, my next desire is to integrate my login system with Phorums, so my users don't have to log in twice.  My login occurs through ajax, and runs through Zend_Auth.

In order to keep my login up, I've created a controller named messageboard, which keeps my login on the page, and then loads the bulletin board through an iframe.  This allows me to keep the Zend component of my login on the same page as my new bulletin board.

Here's my new problem.  In integrating the login systems, I need a way of passing messages back and forth from the Phorum Iframe to the Zend site.  Whether this is having Phorum check my Zend Session to see if it exists, or simply passing an ajax message from Zend to Phorum doesn't matter.  Is it possible to do this, and how?  I believe that two subdomains don't share the same sessions, but I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have a sessions (session cookie to be exact) crossing a domain.

you could add the phorum in the public folder. This should work with the default ZF rewriting rules, couse its only rewriting files which dont exist.

Comment: My previous comment was silly so i deleted it.  Hats off to you, good sir.